# Firebase getRedirectResult returns null response on Firefox and Safari, but not on Chrome

Tags: firefox, firebase-authentication, safari, google-oauth

I am handling my site's authentication through Google with Firebase's `signInWithRedirect` function (cannot use `signInWithPopup`, so don't recommend that) that I'm calling on an onclick event:

```js
loginUser() {
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      const auth = getAuth();
      signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
}
```

In my index.js file I'm listening to Google's response with Firebase's provided `getRedirectResult` function:

```js
getRedirectResult(auth)
    .then(async (res) => {
      if (res && res.user) {
        const isAuthorized = await isUserAuthorized(res.user);
        if (isAuthorized) {
          console.log("User authorized");
          router.push("/");
        } else console.log("User not authorized");
      } else {
        console.log("User not authenticated");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

This works just fine on Chrome, but on Firefox and Safari I'm always getting the `res` variable from the redirect function as null. There are no errors thrown anywhere, and no 40X or 50X errors on any response from Firebase or Google's IAM API.

What I am seeing however, is two iframes from my Firebase auth domain stuck loading and not calling Google's `accounts:signInWithIdp` endpoint:
[image: Iframes are stuck loading]

I have made sure to allow cross-site tracking and remove all content blockers from Safari and Firefox, but they never allow those iframes to load, so the `res` variable is set to null.

I've been searching on the internet for anyone having this problem and, from the small amount of people I found, there's no real solution provided by anyone, so before I throw myself out of the window I figured I'd ask myself and hope for a big brain with a kind soul to appear.

Comment: Having the same issue, I was under the impression that using a proxy will solve, but I'm yet to get a positive result after moving to Cloudflare workers.

The difference is my iframes load fine in Safari, but still null.

Comment: It's been 1 year, May I know if the issue is resolved or not. I am also facing this issue.

Comment: @SimonFernandes nope, ended up convincing HR to allow redirect with popup instead